# android - How to make a jar file from github library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

It's been some days my internet has some problems and I can't use github libraries as we do in gradle . For example due to bad internet connection ,I can't use this :

```
compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
```

i get this error :

```
    Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0
<a href="openFile:F:/AndroidStudioProjects/rasuli/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

any way , now I need a way to compile and make a jar file from libraries, for example If I download the zip file from https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView , How can I make a jar file from this library ?

How can I do so ?

Comment: *Note: Its not necessary to make jar, you can use their code directly by copy paste their file to your project. Of-course it best practice to understand what they write !*

Comment: You can't. It uses resources. You can build an AAR from the library, or you can use the library directly as Kathi points out. Or, when your Internet connection is poor, switch Android Studio into offline mode (Settings > Gradle > Offline mode). "In this case Gradle will use dependencies from the cache. Gradle will not attempt to access the network to perform dependency resolution. If required dependencies are not present in the dependencies' cache, a build execution will fail." https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/gradle-2.html?origin=old_help